# SQL that list all birthdays within the next and previous 14 days

Tags: sql, mysql, date

I have a MySQL `member` table, with a `DOB` field which stores all members' dates of birth in `DATE` format (Notice: it has the "Year" part)

I'm trying to find the correct SQL to:

- List all birthdays within the next 14 days

and another query to:

- List all birthdays within the previous 14 days

Directly comparing the current date by:

```
(DATEDIFF(DOB, now()) <= 14 and DATEDIFF(DOB, now()) >= 0)
```

will fetch nothing since the current year and the DOB year is different.

However, transforming the DOB to 'this year'  won't work at all, because today could be Jan 1 and the candidate could have a DOB of Dec 31 (or vice versa)

It will be great if you can give a hand to help, many thanks! :)

Comment: Wow.  I thought this would be easy.  I've tinkered a bit, and it's much harder than I thought at first glance.  Thanks for the Code Kata!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought was it would be easy to just to use DAYOFYEAR and take the difference, but that actually gets kinda trick near the start/end of a yeay. However:

```
WHERE 
DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) - DAYOFYEAR(dob) BETWEEN 0 AND 14 
OR DAYOFYEAR(dob) - DAYOFYEAR(NOW())  > 351
```

Should work, depending on how much you care about leap years. A "better" answer would probably be to extract the DAY() and MONTH() from the dob and use MAKEDATE() to build a date in the current (or potential past/following) year and compare to that.

Comment: This does not work in a leap year with a birthday in March or later the year.
Example: `dayofyear('2024-02-29') = dayofyear('2014-03-01') = 60`

Answer (score 3):

Here's the simplest code to get the upcoming birthdays for the next x days and previous x days

this query is also not affected by leap-years

```
SELECT name, date_of_birty 
FROM users 
WHERE DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), RIGHT(date_of_birty, 6)))
          BETWEEN 
              DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
          AND
              DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

Comment: This seems quite simple to me, but does not take a birthday at `2015-01-07` if the current date is like `2014-12-30` ... You have to copy that WHERE clause, add it as an `OR` case and modify it like following: `DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE())+1, ...` To add that year to the generated date you compare to.

Answer (score 3):

@Eli had a good response, but hardcoding 351 makes it a little confusing and gets off by 1 during leap years.

This checks if birthday (dob) is within next 14 days.  First check is if in same year.  Second check is if its say Dec 27, you'll want to include Jan dates too.

With `DAYOFYEAR( CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-12-31') )`, we are deciding whether to use 365 or 366 based on the current year (for leap year).

```
SELECT dob
FROM birthdays
WHERE DAYOFYEAR(dob) - DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) BETWEEN 0 AND 14 
OR 
DAYOFYEAR( CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-12-31') ) - ( DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) - DAYOFYEAR(dob) ) BETWEEN 0 AND 14
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy,

We can obtain the nearer birthday (ie the birthday of this year) by this code:

```
dateadd(year,datediff(year,dob,getdate()),DOB)
```

use this in your compares ! it  will work.

Comment: I'm still unsure about it... mind to convert it to mysql version? many thanks!

Comment: You are right, sorry about it, just typed without thinking, just so used to SQL Server. DATE_ADD is equal to SQL Server's DATEADD. Is there an equivalent to DATEDIFF in mySQL, ie something that gives me the distance of two dates in years?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options, I would first try to transform by number of years between current year and row's year (i.e. Add their age).

Another option is day number within the year (but then you have still to worry about the rollover arithmetic or modulo).

Answer (score 0):

This is my query for the 30 days before check:

```
select id from users where 
((TO_DAYS(concat(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y'), '-', DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth, '%m-%d')))-TO_DAYS(NOW()))>=-30 
AND (TO_DAYS(concat(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y'), '-', DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth, '%m-%d')))-TO_DAYS(NOW()))<=0)
OR (TO_DAYS(concat(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y'), '-', DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth, '%m-%d')))-TO_DAYS(NOW()))>=(365-31)
```

and 30 days after:

```
select id from users where 
((TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(concat(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y'), '-', DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth, '%m-%d'))))>=-31 
AND (TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(concat(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y'), '-', DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth, '%m-%d'))))<=0)
OR (TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(concat(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y'), '-', DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth, '%m-%d'))))>=(365-30)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as follow:

```sql
select cm.id from users cm where 
date(concat(
year(curdate()) - (year(subdate(curdate(), 14)) < year(curdate())
and month(curdate()) < month(cm.birthday)) + (year(adddate(curdate(), 14)) > year(curdate())
and month(curdate()) > month(cm.birthday)), date_format(cm.birthday, '-%m-%d'))) between subdate(curdate(), 14)
and adddate(curdate(), 14);
```

It looks like it works fine when the period captures the current and next year or the current and previous year