# Get Upcoming Birthdays Mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to get upcoming birthdays using mysql statement and php. Problem is i've seen some solutions but they use date fields. Unfortunately mine is stored as timestamps. The code below only yields results if the birthdate is after 1970. How can I get a query that will give me current month, next month, month after and so on of upcoming birthdays? And how can I get it to ignore the year as well?

```
    $sql_query = "
        SELECT mem_id, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME( birthdate ),'%d/%m/%Y') 
)
        FROM profiles
        WHERE
            IF ( MONTH( NOW() ) < 12,
              MONTH( DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME( birthdate ),'%Y%m%d') ) = MONTH( NOW() ) + 1,
              MONTH( DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME( birthdate ),'%Y%m%d') ) = 1)
        ORDER BY birthdate";
```

Comment: Took the liberty of making that more readable.

Comment: You mean they're stored as UNIX timestamps as integers, or in `timestamp` type columns?

Comment: The date logic doesn't make sense to me - if NOW is not December, get birthdays that are a month ahead of the current month.  Otherwise, get those for January.

Comment: @OMG He's just avoiding trying to get records for [Undecimber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecimber). Certainly not the most elegant way to do it, but hey... :)

Comment: @deceze: Thx, never heard of that before

Comment: @deceze UNIX timestamps as integers

Comment: This article seems to answer your question pretty well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970615/sql-that-list-all-birthdays-within-the-next-and-previous-14-days/11637388#11637388

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching for this code, but I couldn't find a clean/simple query (that also works with leap-years (29th of february problem))

So i've made my own.

Here's the simplest code to get the upcoming birthdays for the next x days, (this query also displays the birthdays of yesterday (or you can change it to a x number of days in the past)

```
SELECT name, date_of_birty FROM users WHERE 
        DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), RIGHT(date_of_birty, 6)))
                BETWEEN 
                DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                AND
                DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Comment: What happens for people whose birthday is 1st Jan? When it's 30th Dec 2012 this query will be checking to see if 2012-01-01 is in the next 1-5 days when it should be checking for 2013-01-01. Not only do they have to suffer a birthday on new years day, nobody was reminded about it either..

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentMonth = date('n'); // or date('n', strtotime('+1 month')) or whatever
$query = "SELECT ... WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`birthday`)) = $currentMonth";
```

Note though that UNIX timestamps are a terrible choice for storing birthdays:

- They can not store dates prior to 1970 (unless you use negative numbers, which may not work everywhere).
- To query for them in the database you have to convert *all* entries `FROM_UNIXTIME` to compare them, which is quite expensive.

You should use native MySQL [`DATE` columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) to store dates, which allows you to store a much wider range of dates and is much more efficient for queries.