# Query MySql Database for entries with 'Birthday' date field within 30 days from current date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to write a PHP script that queries a MySql database and returns the entries for which the Birthday date field is within the next 30 days.  I am able to do this, but I need to exclude the year from the Birthday date when making the query.  For example, if today's date is 7/10/2013, and the birthday in question is 7/13/1991, obviously these two dates are more than 30 days apart, but if we exclude the year, they are only 3 days apart.  Making this a valid Birthday to return.

The Birthday field is stored as a DATE in the MySql database.

The query I have made so far:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Club WHERE Birthday < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)");
```

What can I do to modify this query to not take the year into account?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970615/sql-that-list-all-birthdays-within-the-next-and-previous-14-days?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783286/get-upcoming-birthdays-mysql-and-php amongst others (though not marking as duplicate, since I don't see any great answers)

Comment: you mean despite the fact that i solved it an hr ago :>

Comment: @NSNolan. that is not true. look at the output. it finds for everyone what their next birthday is going to be, and lists them if they are in the next 30 days

Comment: and if that was the case (i intentially made everyone born in 1973), how did you get all the output for the May and June birthdays.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

`SELECT * FROM Club WHERE month(Birthday) = month(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
and dayofmonth(Birthday) = dayofmonth(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY));`

http://pastebin.com/uEXrXrHT

Comment: You have two queries in that pastebin, I assume you are referring to the second one?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the query I was referring to. I didn't test it but hope it helps. (I didn't change the interval to 30 days so that would need to be updated.)

Comment: Can you please explain what this is doing.  It looks like it is checking to see if

1.) the month of the birthday is the same as the month of the difference between the current date and a 30 day interval 

and 

2.) the dayofmonth of the birthday is the same as the dayofmonth of the difference between the current date and a 30 day interval.

I am not sure if this will actually return the correct results with my understanding of what is going on.  Also if the 30 days is being subtracted from the current date, isn't this query looking for birthdays in the past 30 days not the next 30 days?

Comment: This has been bugging me. The query above does not work. I decided to test it. I also attempted to write some simple queries using math functions but soon realized there are several issues including what happens during the turn of the year that throws simple math out the window. I found the following query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1590/119 (I borrowed one of the other commentors sqlfiddle's to try it out.) Here is a link to the source where I found it: http://www.tsc-web.net/archive/2007/12/mysql-query-howto-select-upcoming-birthdays/

Answer (score 1):

set up your peeps, determine their next birthdate (can be in next calendar year), display the ones having a birthday in next 30 days. works at end of year wrapper (in december), etc

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d881b/4

```
create table peeps
( id int not null auto_increment,
  lastname varchar(40) not null,
birthdate datetime not null,
 primary key (id)
);

insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('sam', '1973-01-01');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('julie', '1973-02-01');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('kim', '1973-03-01');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('fred', '1973-04-01');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('oscar1', '1973-05-01');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('oscar2', '1973-05-02');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('oscar3', '1973-05-04');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('oscar4', '1973-05-06');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('oscar5', '1973-05-08');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('oscar6', '1973-05-10');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('oscar7', '1973-05-12');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('oscar8', '1973-05-14');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('oscar9', '1973-05-16');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('oscar10', '1973-05-18');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('oscar11', '1973-05-20');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('oscar12', '1973-05-22');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('oscar13', '1973-05-24');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('Felix the Cat1', '1973-06-01');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('Felix the Cat2', '1973-06-05');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('Felix the Cat3', '1973-06-07');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('Bonehead7', '1973-07-01');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('Bonehead8', '1973-08-01');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('Bonehead9', '1973-09-01');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('Bonehead10', '1973-10-01');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('Bonehead11', '1973-11-01');
insert peeps (lastname,birthdate) values ('Bonehead12', '1973-12-01');

create table peeps_next_birthday
(id int not null,
 next_birthdate datetime not null
 );

insert into peeps_next_birthday (id,next_birthdate) select id,birthdate from peeps;


UPDATE peeps_next_birthday set next_birthdate=date_add(next_birthdate, interval (year(curdate())-year(next_birthdate)) year);

update peeps_next_birthday set next_birthdate=date_add(next_birthdate,interval 1 year)
where curdate()>next_birthdate;

   ///  *************************** now show the birthdays in the coming 30 days

select t2.id,t2.lastname,t1.next_birthdate
from peeps_next_birthday t1
join peeps t2
on t2.id=t1.id
where datediff(t1.next_birthdate,curdate())<=30
```

Comment: +1 It works, and with an index it'd be blazingly fast.  Can you edit the queries into your answer? (in case SQLfiddle dies).  It would be nice to be able to solve this without having to have a separate record of the next birthday though.

Comment: yeah that was just a reporting table to be dropped

Answer (score 0):

This was a little tricky, but here is my solution:

```
SELECT
    birthday,
    -- Shift the birthday into the current year
    CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', MONTH(birthday), '-', DAY(birthday)) AS DATE) AS BirthdayInCurrentYear
FROM Club
WHERE CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', MONTH(birthday), '-', DAY(birthday)) AS DATE)
    BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY;
```

This query works with **leap years** <del>and with dates in the following year</del>. You can test and verify using my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20860/2).

This might not be the fastest solution as it creates a VARCHAR and parses it back to a DATETIME. Unfortunately I did not find a better way the set only the year part of a DATETIME.

Comment: i added to the year the curdate less their birth year, then bumped it up another year if their birthday passed for this calendar year

Comment: @ZombieHunter this will fail at the end of the year - it doesn't find birthdays at the start of the next year.

Comment: @therefromhere so when now is Dec 25 you are saying his won't work ?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested it but I think that this will do and from reading it is clear what it does.

```
SELECT * FROM Club WHERE DAYOFYEAR(Birthday) BETWEEN DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) AND DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) + 30;
```

Comment: Does this work with leap years? Well, it does not: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/12197

Comment: this won't work at the end of the year. it will say between 350 and 15